# Routing with AngularJS and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile, mobile, routes

I'm working on a jQuery/jQuery-mobile based webapp and I was asked to use AngularJS.
As expected, I have some problem on handling routing. I know there are lots of people discussing about it, but still I haven't found a working solution.

I have already read [this page](http://simonguest.com/2013/04/08/jquery-mobile-and-angularjs-working-together/) that someone suggested, but loading first jQuery mobile and then angular doesn't help.

Now I'm taking a look to [this library](https://github.com/angular-widgets/angular-jqm) but I'm not sure the company will let me use it, 'cause it's still on alpha stage and my work could became (hopefully) a production webapp.
I'm now wondering how can I let JQM handle AngularJS route too, I think this could be the best solution for me.

Has anyone managed it? Can you provide me a working example or another possible solution?
Thanks.

Comment: the question is what do you need jQuery for?
is it a constraint?

Comment: It's not up to me, there are some features I did not develop and I can't modify that need JQM

Comment: do you have to interact with the angular routing with jQuery?
you can just programmatically set the page location and you should not have problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to solve it is to disable JQM routing, try this:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false; 
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false; 
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false; 
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks. I put this code in my app.config($routeProvider).